# How to do Html encoding in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Surprised that I cannot find such simple need in 15 minutes.

I am forming string based on user input and it might have some special characters, like < or /. To be safe I want to add html encoding to such line of code (typescript):

`` const suggest: any = { id: '', title: `Suggest ${q} ${type}`, type: type, query: q }; ``

**title** later used as **typeaheadOptionField** and I do not see an easy way to use innerHTML.

Thanks!

Comment: TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, meaning any valid JS is valid TS.  Is there a reason that using the HTML encoding provided in other JS answers on StackOverflow isn't working for you?

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel typical JS advice I found is to use JQuery, e.g. $('<div>').text(unsafestring).html()

Comment: There are non-jQuery examples on SO posts:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124052